# i have table formatted data and wanted to convert into tuple format

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tuples

I have a csv file mentioned as below screen shot ...

[image]

and i want to convert the whole file in the below format in python.

[image]

Comment: what are you headers of csv file?

Comment: Use `tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this after reading your CSV file correct file path.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file", names=["Sentence", "Value"])
result = [(row["Sentence"], row["Value"]) for index, row in df.iterrows()]
print(result)
```

Comment: That's is exactly what i was looking for ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a single line using `apply()` method of dataframe

`df.apply(lambda x: x.tolist(), axis=1)`

OR

`df.values.tolist()` will also work